# What is the equivalent DISTINCT(sql server) in the Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a Table(Send) with columns(Id, UserId,SendDate)  and another table(Receive) with columns(Id,SendId,UserName).

I want show all records in SendTable with all RecieveUserName.

for example.

```
(Send)
1   1   2013
2   2   2013


(Recieve)
1   1   Jack
2   1   Ema
3   2   Alex
4   2   Sara


Result
1   1   2013  Jack, Ema
2   2   2013  Alex, Sara
```

I use this query in `SqlServer` (The DISTINCT keyword eliminates duplicate rows from the results of a SELECT statement)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c2.Id,
(SELECT    STR( UserName )+ ','
 FROM         dbo.Reciver c1
 WHERE     c1.SendId = c2.id FOR XML PATH('')) Concatenated, c2.SendDate, c2.UserId
 FROM         dbo.Send AS c2 INNER JOIN
 dbo.Reciver ON c2.Id = dbo.Reciver.SendId
```

How do this query in Linq?

Comment: Can you show how you would do this with LINQ without the "distinct"? I ask because I doubt it's "distinct" that's giving you problems.

Comment: I use this query in sql server. I want find the equivalent of this in linq.

Comment: Then please edit your question summary so that you do not only ask for how to translate "distinct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me that you need to use Distinct in this Linq query. Assuming you have the relationships between tables set up on your linq datacontext, you can do something like this:

```
var result = from s in context.Send
             select new {
                 id = s.Id,
                 userId = s.UserId,
                 date = s.SendDate,
                 users = s.Receive.Select(u => u.UserName)
             }
```

Note: `users` will an `IEnumerable<String>` - you can use `string.Join()` on the client to join the names into a string.

**Update**

To return users as a string to first need to 'switch' to Linq To Objects by calling `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` and the Linq to Sql query.

```
var output = from s in result.AsEnumerable()
             select new {
                 id = s.id,
                 userId = s.userId,
                 date = s.date,
                 users = string.Join(", ", s.users)
             }
```

Also see [Gert Arnolds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782400/7793) for a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks, Can I use a string(users) instead of a users list `( users = s.Receive.Select(u => u.UserName))` that join all username into a string?

Comment: You can try `string.Join(",", s.Receive.Select(u => u.UserName))` but you may get an error that it can't be translated into sql. In that case you have to loop through the results and do the `string.Join` on the client side. eg not in the sql select statement that your linq gets translated into.

Comment: Thanks, yes i get error `this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` . How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

`Distinct` is also available in `LINQ`.

For example

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

Product[] products = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                   new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 }, 
                   new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 10 }, 
                   new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 9 } };
var lstDistProduct = products.Distinct();
foreach (Product p in list1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Code + " : " + p.Name);
}
```

Will return all rows.

```
var list1 = products.DistinctBy(x=> x.Code);

foreach (Product p in list1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Code + " : " + p.Name);
}
```

will return 9 and 4

Comment: Thanks, but i use this query in `SqlServer` . 

The DISTINCT keyword eliminates duplicate rows from the results of a SELECT statement

Comment: `DistinctBy` is not standard linq.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can only be done in two steps. Not because of the `DISTINCT`, but because of the `FOR XML`. The C# equivalent of the latter is `String.Join()`, but you can't use that in a linq to entities statement directly. So you must collect the required data first, then switch to linq to objects (by applying AsEnumerable) and then do the concatenation and distinct:

```cs
 db.Sends
   .Where(s => s.Receivers.Any())
   .Select(s => new { 
                       s.Id, 
                       Concatenated = s.Receivers.Select(r => r.UserName)
                       s.SendDate,
                       s.UserId
                    })
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(x => new { 
                       s.Id, 
                       Concatenated = String.Join(", ", x.Concatenated)
                       s.SendDate,
                       s.UserId
                    })
   .Distinct()
```